# It is possible to combine a reflector and a refractor telescope together?

Tags: observational-astronomy, telescope, refractor-telescope

I know it sounds crazy, but is it possible to 
connect a reflector telescope and a refractor telescopes (like monocular for bird watching) together to build a better telescope?

Comment: It's going to be difficult, and it will not work very well if the telescopes differ in any significant way. If you want to use both eyes, consider using a binoviewer adapter instead (looks like the rear part of binoculars, has two eyepieces, plugs into the focuser of a regular monocular telescope). But do some research beforehand, because these are not necessarily plug and play either - there might be requirements of backfocus, etc.

Comment: You want a serial connection of the two? Then your main optical properties (image resolution, light collecting area) will be dominated by the first one simply, and the whole exercise is naught.

Comment: Finder scopes work. You're talking serious cash to match your 8" reflector with an 8" short focus refractor.

Answer (score 1):

> ...is it possible to connect a reflector telescope and a refractor telescopes (like monocular for bird watching) together...

Yes, a properly focused telescope (for someone who's not near-sighted) will have infinity conjugate focal points; parallel rays in make parallel rays out.

If the telescope is set up for 50x magnification (f=600 mm objective, f=12 mm eyepiece) then a 1 degree field of view (FOV) in the sky will be a 50 degree apparent FOV at the output of the first eyepiece.

Alas, a second 8 x bird-watching monocular may only have a 7 degree input FOV so we will indeed get 50 x 8 = 400x magnification, but of a 0.14 degree field.

That's just what you would get looking through a single telescope set up for 400x (say f=1200 mm objective, 2x Barlow and f=6 mm eyepiece).

In other words, you could do this, but...

> ...to build a better telescope?

I'm not sure it would be better in any possible way if it's for *looking through*.

However, if you have [an old CMOS imager webcam from the 1990's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_Room_coffee_pot) with giant pixels and you want to blow up the primary focal plane of the first telescope to get some useful resolution, this might be a suboptimal solution. You could remove the eyepiece of the second bird-watching monocular and put the image sensor with too-large pixel size there and get better resolution than if you'd put it at the focal plane of the first telescope.

A better way to solve this unlikely problem might be to simply use [positive or eyepiece projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophotography#Equipment_setups) with the first telescope's eyepiece moved outwards so that it's final focal point moves in from infinity to say roughly 8 times its focal length.

That would have the same effect but without adding the monocular.